# Avoid some fields to check duplicate row by attach method laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

**Hey,**

Wanna Laravel `attach` method automatically check duplicate row in database,While i have `created_at` field in my pivot table, so attach method can't modify duplicate rows, what can i do?

Something like this:

```
$user->performs()->attach($perform,['created_at' => Carbon::now()]);
```

**EDITED:**

I tried to use `user_id` and `perform_id` as primary but dont work as i want

**FIXED**

Fixed by this instead of id in table:

```
$table->primary(['user_id','perform_id']);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically check duplicate row"? Do you want to ignore those that are already attached? You might be better off using `->sync()` in that case

Comment: @devk No!, I want unique rows in table not duplicate but i dont want check it manually in function i want it throws error if it was duplicate row

Comment: you need to make a composite key in case, its an option. i.e. user_id and perform_id should be composite key